# Number of decimals to round to after division so that reversing the operation is precise

Tags: arithmetic, rounding-unit

I'm dividing number **A** (positive, with up to 2 decimal places) by another number **B** (positive, up to 3 decimal places) to arrive at my result, **C**.

I'd like to round **C** to the fewest decimal places so that multiplying it back with **B** is always equal to **A** after rounding to 2 digits.

Is there a method for determining how many decimal places are needed in **C** for the assumption:

> round(**C** * **B**, 2) = **A**

to always be true?

I don't *think* significant figures/digits are important here, as I'm not concerned with measurement precision in any of the results -- I just need the fewest decimal places in **C** to satisfy that assumption. It may also be worth noting that I can't change the value of **A** or of **B**.

My gut tells me the answer is simply the total of the decimal places in **A** and **B** (5), but I can't seem to find anything online that covers rounding *then* reversing the operations.

Ultimately, I'm hoping to find the method for determining this number of decimal places so that perhaps I can variably set the number of decimal places to include in **C** based on whether there happen to be trailing zeroes in the other values.

Comment: Your terminology "decimals" is not standard. Do you mean significant figures, or decimal places? E.g. 12.345 is five significant figures and three decimal places.

Comment: Sorry, decimal places in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Am I right in thinking that $A$ and $B$ are exact to 2 and 3 decimal places respectively?  That being the case, we only need to worry about $C$.

Let's write it as $C=c+\delta c$, where $\delta c$ is the bit you're wanting to discard. We have

$$\begin{align}
B(c+\delta c)&=A \\
Bc&=A-B\delta c
\end{align}$$
Therefore $Bc$ will round back to $A$ as required provided $|B\delta c|<0.005$.  If $C$ is rounded to $n$ decimal places, $|\delta c|\le 0.5 \times 10^{-n}=0.005\times 10^{-(n-2)}$, so we just need
$$\begin {align}
|B|&<10^{n-2} \\
n&>2+\log_{10}|B|
\end {align}
$$

So contrary to what you thought, the number of digits in $B$ turns out to be key.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. So in my case, if I can safely assume *B* will never have more than 4 digits (e.g. 9.999 max), then rounding to 3 decimals should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes that sounds right!

Answer (score 0):

How many decimals to the left of C depends upon how many are to the right of B.  Similarly, the number of decimals you need to the right of C depends upon the size of B.

$(C + \epsilon_c)*(B+\epsilon_b) = CB + C \epsilon_b + B\epsilon_c$  (the $\epsilon_b\epsilon_c$ term is insignificant and can be ignored)

If you want $C \epsilon_b + B\epsilon_c < 0.01$ then $\epsilon_b < 0.005/C$ and $ \epsilon_c < 0.005/B$